# Bean validation and SOAP fault messages

Tags: java, web-services, soap, ejb, bean-validation

I'm learning bean validation and want to apply it in a webservice.

I would like to build a SOAP web service, implementing it using EJBs. Port implementation is facade to internal implementation structure.
As transport objects I generated classes from XML schema, while in internal structure I use JPA entities.

I would like to use bean validation annotations on JPA entities and EJB methods.

Is it possible somehow to use constraint violations as validation results in the facade to build fault messages?

Is there any good practice how to achieve that, since xsd types and jpa entities have slightly different structure and direct messages from validation might not be totally suitable for faults?

Comment: IIRC there should be a `message` attribute in the constraint annotation.

Comment: Yes, message helps, but what about structure? I might have collection of collections. Fault should tell me, where violation happend.